# Split a single cell at line breaks

Tags: excel, vba

I have a spreadsheet that has data in a single cell separated by line breaks.  I need to split the cell into separate rows so that I can remove some data and recombine. Like this:

| Item | Status |
| --- | --- |
| 285T1150-3 | 285T0680-1 1 Complete 285T1145-7//D 1 ATS-182 285T1146-1//D 1 Complete 363A4872P4 1 No Router |

Convert to this:

| Item | Status |
| --- | --- |
| 285T1150-3 | 285T0680-1 1 Complete |
| 285T1150-3 | 285T1145-7//D 1 ATS-182 |
| 285T1150-3 | 285T1146-1//D 1 Complete |
| 285T1150-3 | 363A4872P4 1 No Router |

This is the code I've been using:

```
        check_col = colArray(0)
        ColLastRow = Range(check_col & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
        For Each Rng In Range(check_col & "1" & ":" & check_col & ColLastRow)
            If InStr(Rng.Value, vbLf) Then
                Rng.EntireRow.Copy
                Rng.EntireRow.Insert
                
                For i = 0 To UBound(colArray)
                    c = colArray(i)
                    
                    Set currentrng = Range(c & Rng.Row)
                    Set upperRng = currentrng.Offset(-1, 0)
                
                    upperRng.Value = Mid(currentrng.Value, 1, InStr(currentrng.Value, vbLf) - 1)
                    currentrng.Value = Mid(currentrng.Value, Len(upperRng.Value) + 2, Len(currentrng.Value))
                Next i
            End If
        Next
```

Which works perfectly.  It just takes a very long time.  Sometimes upwards of 5-8 minutes.  Is there a way I can streamline this so that it runs a little faster?

Comment: I strongly recommend using PowerQuery for this.

Comment: My knowledge of PowerQuery is extremely limited.  I wouldn't even know how to start.

Comment: Would your data be delimited by a single line-feed character? Or multiple? In other words; are those blank lines in your sample data actually blank?

Comment: The data in the cell is delimited by a single line-feed.  However, the sheet has ~1400 rows which is where it gets bogged down.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For this particular data transformation, Power Query seems to be (and is) much powerful/faster than VBA like [JvdV](https://stackoverflow.com/users/9758194/jvdv) mentionned in the comments.

Assuming there is a single line-feed in the column `Statuts`, you can get your output by making two steps/lines of M code and that with the use of the function [Splitter.SplitTextByDelimiter](https://learn.microsoft.com/fr-fr/powerquery-m/splitter-splittextbydelimiter) :

```
let
    Source = Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="Table1"]}[Content],
    #"Split Column by Delimiter" = Table.ExpandListColumn(Table.TransformColumns(Source, {{"Status", Splitter.SplitTextByDelimiter("#(lf)", QuoteStyle.Csv), let itemType = (type nullable text) meta [Serialized.Text = true] in type {itemType}}}), "Status")
in
    #"Split Column by Delimiter"
```

[image]

For ~1.4k rows, the query will take less than 2~3 seconds to refresh.

##### DEMO :

[image]

Comment: Can I integrate that into an existing VBA macro?

Comment: Yes, you will need to add this line to your VBA code : `ActiveWorkbook.Connections("Query - Table1").Refresh`. If needed, a demo was added to my answer to explain how to create the query with Power Query.

Comment: Perfect!  The initial data is actually part of a database query.  I was able to split it before I loaded it.  Saved me a massive headache.

Comment: @Myykro, well done! Glad to hear you learned something new **and** was able to implement this to save you a ton of time/effort. And a good explaination by L'Artiste! +

Comment: Good for you @Mykkro and thanks JvdV for the kind words, I really appreciate it.

Answer (score 7):

I'd strongly recommend PowerQuery for the task at hand:

- Imagine the following sample data;

  [image]
- Select data, then load it into PQ as per below GIF;

  [image]
- PQ will open, follow the steps as below GIF;

  [image]
- Close PQ and save changes. Result will look like:

  [image]

Answer (score 4):

Additional variant to posted already:

```
Sub foo()
    Dim dic As Object: Set dic = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
    Dim x&, cl As Range, data As Range, ws As Worksheet, spStr, dKey
    Set ws = ActiveSheet
    
    Set data = ws.Range("B1:B" & Cells(Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp).Row)
    x = 0
    For Each cl In data
        For Each slpstr In Split(cl, Chr(10))
            If slpstr <> "" Then
                dic.Add x, ws.Cells(cl.Row, "A").Value & "|" & slpstr
                x = x + 1
            End If
    Next slpstr, cl
    Set ws = Worksheets.Add: ws.Name = "Result"
    x = 1
    For Each dKey In dic
        ws.Cells(x, "A").Value = Split(dic(dKey), "|")(0)
        ws.Cells(x, "B").Value = Split(dic(dKey), "|")(1)
        x = x + 1
    Next dKey
    ws.[A:B].Columns.AutoFit
End Sub
```

**For ~1.4k rows will take less than 1 second** (tested).

demo:

[image]

Comment: Elegant solution!  The PowerQuery option does end up being faster just because it splits the data before it's loaded but your code definitely works.

Comment: Thank you, I've still use mso 2007 in my home machine and it doesn't have any new features such as power query and so on, but "old but not useless" ... .