# Excel: divide text field in to separate columns

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have the following input table:

| Sales Order | Asset Serial Number | Asset Model | Licence Class | License Type | License Name | Account Name |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 10000 | 1234, 5643, 3463 | test-pro | A123 | software | LIC-0002, LIC-0188, LIC-0188, LIC-0013 | ABC |
| 2000 | 5678, 9846, 5639 | test-pro | A123 | software | LIC-00107, LIC-08608, LIC-009, LIC-0610 | ABC |

Here the screenshot
[image: 1]

I need it transformed into form:

[image: 2].

I tried it first with the Replace function & transponate it but I didn't find a way to add the other empty columns other than do it manually.
My second thought was the text-to-column function, didn't work either.

Comment: Welcome to SO. You've used twice the same image, edit your question and add correct output. Also, post what you've tried.

Comment: Formula cannot insert rows. You will need VBA macro to insert rows.

Comment: @shrivallabha.redij I already feared that answer as I'm not prolific in VBA just yet. I will try and post my progress. If you got some tipps I'm all ears.

Comment: Are you sure you want empty cells? If not, this can be done with a few steps in powerquery. Not hard to do and if interested we can link you to answers showing how to.

Comment: As I have a lot of datasets I think it is necessary to have this empty cells. But maybe I misunderstand it so please go ahead and send me to the answers.

Comment: if the empty cells are just a visual requirement than you could use conditional formatting to set the font color to white ...

Comment: Here are some links: [1](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64313519/9758194), [2](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66509851/9758194) and [3](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73403413/9758194). There will be more out there, but this will get you there.

Comment: **Update**: @michaoe I provided also a Power Query solution. I was curious on how this approach would work so I added to my answer.  I was expecting something more concise, but at the end several transformations are required too and not all of them via PQ UI, so M code was required.

Answer (score 1):

Here two solutions one using Excel formulas and the other one using Power Query. See **Explanation** section for more information about each approach:

## Excel

It is possible with excel without using Power Query, but several manipulations are required. On cell `I2` put the following formula:

```
=LET(counts, BYROW(F2:F3, LAMBDA(a, LEN(a) - LEN(SUBSTITUTE(a, ",", "")))), del, "|",
  emptyRowsSet, MAP(A2:A3, B2:B3, C2:C3, D2:D3, E2:E3, F2:F3, G2:G3, counts,
  LAMBDA(a,b,c,d,e,f,g,cnts, LET(rep, REPT(";",cnts),a&rep &del& b&rep &del& c&rep &del&
  d&rep &del& e&rep &del& SUBSTITUTE(f,", ",";") &del& g&rep  ))),
  emptyRowsSetByCol, TEXTSPLIT(TEXTJOIN("&",,emptyRowsSet), del, "&"),
  byColResult, BYCOL(emptyRowsSetByCol, LAMBDA(a, TEXTJOIN(";",,a))),
  singleLine, TEXTJOIN(del,,byColResult),
  TRANSPOSE(TEXTSPLIT(singleLine,";",del))
)
```

Here is the output:

[image: Sample excel file output]

### Update

A simplified version of previous formula is the following one:

```
=LET(counts, BYROW(F2:F3, LAMBDA(a, LEN(a) - LEN(SUBSTITUTE(a, ",", "")))), del, "|",
  reps, MAKEARRAY(ROWS(A2:G3),COLUMNS(A2:G3), LAMBDA(a,b, INDEX(counts, a,1))),
  emptyRowsSetByCol, MAP(A2:G3, reps, LAMBDA(a,b, IF(COLUMN(a)=6, 
  SUBSTITUTE(a,", ",";"), a&REPT(";",b)))),
  byColResult, BYCOL(emptyRowsSetByCol, LAMBDA(a, TEXTJOIN(";",,a))),
  singleLine, TEXTJOIN(del,,byColResult),
  TRANSPOSE(TEXTSPLIT(singleLine,";",del))
)
```

## Power Query

The following M Code provides the expected result:

```
let
  Source = Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="TB_Sales"]}[Content],
  #"Changed Type" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(Source,{{"Sales Order", type text}}),
  #"Split License Name" = Table.ExpandListColumn(Table.TransformColumns(#"Changed Type", {{"License Name", 
    Splitter.SplitTextByDelimiter(", ", QuoteStyle.Csv), 
      let itemType = (type nullable text) meta [Serialized.Text = true] in type {itemType}}}), "License Name"),
  ListOfColumns = List.Difference(Table.ColumnNames(#"Split License Name"), {"License Name"}),
  RemainingColumns = List.Difference(Table.ColumnNames(#"Changed Type"), ListOfColumns),
  RemoveDups = (lst as list) =>
    let
      concatList = (left as list, right as list) => List.Transform(List.Positions(left), each left{_}&"_"& right{_}),
      prefixList = Table.Column(#"Split License Name", "Sales Order"),
      tmp = concatList(prefixList, lst),
      output = List.Accumulate(tmp, {}, (x, y) => x & {if List.Contains(x, y) then null else y})
    in 
      output,
  replaceValues = List.Transform(ListOfColumns, each RemoveDups(Table.Column(#"Split License Name", _))),
  #"Added Empty Rows" = Table.FromColumns(
    replaceValues & Table.ToColumns(Table.SelectColumns(#"Split License Name", RemainingColumns)),
    ListOfColumns & RemainingColumns),
    #"Extracted Text After Delimiter" = Table.TransformColumns(#"Added Empty Rows", {{"Sales Order", 
      each Text.AfterDelimiter(_, "_"), type text}, {"Asset Serial Number", each Text.AfterDelimiter(_, "_"), type text}, 
      {"Asset Model", each Text.AfterDelimiter(_, "_"), type text}, {"Licence Class", 
      each Text.AfterDelimiter(_, "_"), type text}, {"License Type", each Text.AfterDelimiter(_, "_"), type text}, 
      {"Account Name", each Text.AfterDelimiter(_, "_"), type text}}),
  #"Reordered Columns" = Table.ReorderColumns(#"Extracted Text After Delimiter",{"Sales Order", "Asset Serial Number", "Asset Model", 
      "Licence Class", "License Type", "License Name", "Account Name"})
in
  #"Reordered Columns"
```

And here is the output:

[image: PQ final result screenshot]

And the corresponding Excel Output:

[image: PQ output in Excel]

## Explanation

Here we provide the explanation for each approach: Excel formula and Power Query.

### Excel Formula

We need to calculate how many empty rows we need to add based on **License Name** column values. We achieve that via `counts` name from `LET`:

```
BYROW(F2:F3, LAMBDA(a, LEN(a) - LEN(SUBSTITUTE(a, ",", ""))))
```

The output for this case is: `{3;3}`, i.e `2x1` array, which represents how many empty rows we need to add for each input row.

Next we need to build the set that includes empty rows. We name it `emptyRowsSet` and the calculation is as follow:

```
MAP(A2:A3, B2:B3, C2:C3, D2:D3, E2:E3, F2:F3, G2:G3, counts,
  LAMBDA(a,b,c,d,e,f,g,cnts, 
  LET(rep, REPT(";",cnts),a&rep &del& b&rep &del& c&rep &del&
    d&rep &del& e&rep &del& SUBSTITUTE(f,", ",";") &del& g&rep)))
```

We use inside `MAP` an additional `LET` function to avoid repetition of `rep` value. Because we want to consider the content of **License Name** as additional rows we replace the `,` by `;` (we are going to consider this token as a row delimiter). We use `del` (`|`) as a delimiter that will serve as a column delimiter.

Here would be the intermediate result of `emptyRowsSet`:

```
10000;;;|1234, 5643, 3463;;;|test-pro;;;|A123;;;|software;;;|LIC-0002;LIC-0188;LIC-0188;LIC-0013|ABC;;;
2000;;;|5678, 9846, 5639;;;|test-pro;;;|A123;;;|software;;;|LIC-00107;LIC-08608;LIC-009;LIC-0610|ABC;;;
```

As you can see additional `;` where added per number of items we have in **License Name** column per row. In the sample data the number of empty rows to add is the same per row, but it could be different.

The rest is how to accommodate the content of `emptyRowsSet` in the way we want. Because we cannot invoke `TEXTSPLIT` and `BYROW` together because we get `#CALC!` (Nested Array error). We need to try to circumvent this.

For example the following produces an error (`#CALC!`):

```
=BYROW(A1:A2,LAMBDA(a, TEXTSPLIT(a,"|")))
```

where the range `A1:A2` has the following: `={"a|b";"c|d"}`. We don't get the desired output: `={"a","b";"c","d"}`. In short the output of `BYROW` should be a single column so any `LAMBDA` function that expands the columns will not work.

In order to do circumvent that we can do the following:

1. Convert the input into a single string joining each row by `;` for example. Now we have column delimiter (`|`) and row delimiter (`;`)
2. Use `TEXTSPLIT` to generate the array (`2x2` in this case), identifying the columns and the row via both delimiters.

We can do it as follow (showing the output of each step on the right)

```
=TEXTSPLIT(TEXTJOIN(";",,A1:A2),"|",";") -> 1) "a|b;c|d" -> 2) ={"a","b";"c","d"}
```

We are using the same idea here (but using `&` for joining each row). The name `emptyRowsSetByCol`:

```
TEXTSPLIT(TEXTJOIN("&",,emptyRowsSet), del, "&")
```

Would produce the following intermediate result, now organized by columns (*Table 1*):

| Sales Order | Asset Serial Number | Asset Model | License Class | License Type | License Name | Account Name |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| `10000;;;` | `1234, 5643, 3463;;;` | `test-pro;;;` | `A123;;;` | `software;;;` | `LIC-0002;LIC-0188;LIC-0188;LIC-0013` | `ABC;;;` |
| `2000;;;` | `5678, 9846, 5639;;;` | `test-pro;;;` | `A123;;;` | `software;;;` | `LIC-00107;LIC-08608;LIC-009;LIC-0610` | `ABC;;;` |

**Note:** The header are just for illustrative purpose, but it is not part of the output.

Now we need to concatenate the information per column and for that we can use `BYCOL` function. We name the result: `byColResult` of the following formula:

```
BYCOL(emptyRowsSetByCol, LAMBDA(a, TEXTJOIN(";",,a)))
```

The intermediate result would be:

| Sales Order | Asset Serial Number | Asset Model | License Class | License Type | License Name | Account Name |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| `10000;;;;2000;;;` | `1234, 5643, 3463;;;;5678, 9846, 5639;;;` | `test-pro;;;;test-pro;;;` | `A123;;;;A123;;;` | `software;;;;software;;;` | `LIC-0002;LIC-0188;LIC-0188;LIC-0013;LIC-00107;LIC-08608;LIC-009;LIC-0610` | `ABC;;;;ABC;;;` |

`1x7` array and on each column the content already delimited by `;` (ready for the final split).

Now we need to apply the same idea as before i.e. convert everything to a single string and then split it again.

First we convert everything to a single string and name the result: `singleLine`:

```
TEXTJOIN(del,,byColResult)
```

Next we need to do the final split:

```
TRANSPOSE(TEXTSPLIT(singleLine,";",del))
```

We need to transpose the result because `SPLIT` processes the information row by row.

#### Update

I provided a simplified version of the initial approach which requires less steps, because we can obtain the result of the `MAP` function directly by columns.

The main idea is to treat the input range `A2:G3` all at once. In order to do that we need to have all the `MAP` input arrays of the same shape. Because we need to take into account the number of empty rows to add (`;`), we need to build this second array of the same shape. The name `reps`, is intended to create this second array as follow:

```
MAKEARRAY(ROWS(A2:G3),COLUMNS(A2:G3), 
 LAMBDA(a,b, INDEX(counts, a,1)))
```

The intermediate output will be:

```
3|3|3|3|3|3|3
3|3|3|3|3|3|3
```

which represents a `2x7` array, where on each row we have the number of empty rows to add.

Now the name `emptyRowsSetByCol`:

```
MAP(A2:G3, reps, 
 LAMBDA(a,b, IF(COLUMN(a)=6, SUBSTITUTE(a,", ",";"), 
 a&REPT(";",b))))
```

Produces the same intermediate result as in above *Table 1*. We treat different the information from column 6 (**License Name**) replacing the `,` with `;`. For other columns just add as many `;` as empty rows we need to add for each input row. The rest of the formula is just similar to the first approach.

### Power Query

`#"Split License Name"` is a standard Power Query (PQ) UI function: *Split Column by Delimiter*.

To generate empty rows we do it by removing duplicates elements on each column that requires this transformation, i.e. all columns except **License Name**. We do it all at once identifying the columns that require such transformation. In order to do that we define two lists:

- `ListOfColumns`: Identifies the columns we are going to do the transformation, because we need to do it in all columns except for **License Name**. We do it by difference via the PQ function: `List.Difference()`.
- `RemainingColumns`: To build back again the table, we need to identify the columns don't require such transformation. We use same idea via `List.Difference()`, based on `ListOfColumns` list.

The user defined function `RemoveDups(lst as list)` does the magic of this transformation.

Because we need to remove duplicates, but having unique elements based on each initial row, we use the first column **Sales Order** as a prefix, so we can "clean" the column within each partition.

In order to do that we define inside of `RemoveDups()` function a new user defined function `concatList()` to add the first column as prefix.

```
concatList = (left as list, right as list) =>
  List.Transform(List.Positions(left), each left{_}&"-"& right{_}),
```

we concatenate each element of the lists (row by row) using a underscore delimiter (`_`). Later we are going to use this delimiter to remove the first column as prefix added at this point.

To remove duplicates and replace them with `null` we use the following logic:

```
output = List.Accumulate(tmp, {}, (x, y) => 
  x & {if List.Contains(x, y) then null else y})
```

where `tmp` is a modified list (`lst`) with the first column as prefix.

Now we invoke the `List.Transform()` function for all the columns that require the transformation using as `transform` (second input argument) the function we just defined previously:

```
replaceValues = List.Transform(ListOfColumns, each 
  RemoveDups(Table.Column(#"Split License Name", _))),
```

`#"Added Empty Rows"` represents the step of this calculation and the output will be the following table:

[image: PQ output of the step: #Added Empty Rows]

The step `#"Extracted Text After Delimiter"` is just to remove the prefix we added and for that we use standard PQ UI *Transform->Extract->Text After Delimiter*.

Finally we need to reorder the column to put in a way it is expected via the step: `#"Reordered Columns"` using PQ UI functionality.

Comment: Thank you for the extensive effort you put into this! Worked like a charm!